# Python: Function won't return/yield passed matrix after modification

Tags: python, list, recursion, sudoku

The following function `solve()` takes a 2D list (A sudoku puzzle) `grid` and must solve the puzzle by perform the backtracking operations and yield a solution instead it yields nothing and `stopiteration` occurs.

```
# Backtracking Algorithm 
def solve(grid: list[list]): 
    for row in range(9):  
        for column in range(9)
            # Only if position holds 0
            if not grid[row][column]:  
                for number in range(1, 10):
                    # Sets number if its possible else reverts
                    # is_possible returns just Booleans
                    if is_possible(grid, row, column, number):
                        grid[row][column] = number
                        solve(grid)
                        grid[row][column] = 0
                return None
    # print(print(*[row for row in matrix], sep='\n')
    yield grid

some_matrix = [[...],...] #This is a sudoku matrix
solution = solve(some_matrix)
print(next(solution))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Github\PySudokuSolver\main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Github\PySudokuSolver\main.py", line 47, in main
    print(next(solution))
StopIteration
```

However when I try to print the matrix inside the function it works fine.
I've also tried just returning the grid instead of yielding it first but it returns None.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: `solve(grid)` has no `return`. How are nested recursive calls supposed to know whether a child call they spawned solved the puzzle or not? Try passing the solved grid all the way back up the call stack, or a boolean that indicates that a solution was found. It's odd to return a generator that only has at most one item in it. That's not the point of generators.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my query. I forgot to use the return case in the nested If statement now it is perfectly working.  
 Should I post my fix after the question so 
 that others can also get help?

Comment: It's allowed to answer your own question. That's better than putting an answer inside the question itself too.